# mysterious c++ segmentation fault

Tags: c++, g++, segmentation-fault

I'm new to C++ and am having some difficulty with this simple problem. The following code exhibits some strange behaviour. I'm trying to print a bunch of numbers to a text file and time how long it takes. For smaller n (< 5000), the code runs but the text file that gets created is jibberish. For n > 10000 the program crashes with the error "segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Here is my code in its' entirety:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double listN(int n)
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    ofstream resultsfile;

    resultsfile.open("Number.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
    resultsfile << i + "\n";
    }

    resultsfile.close();

    return (1000 * (clock() - start)/(double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
} 


int main()
{
    const int NUM_RUNS = 20;
    double time = 0;
    int n;

    cout << "Enter the value n:";
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RUNS; i++)
    {
     time += listN(n);
    }

    cout << time / NUM_RUNS <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea as to the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to print the integer and the new line into the file, and not to "add" them, this line

```
resultsfile << i + "\n";
```

should be

```
resultsfile << i << "\n";
```

Next time, compile your program with `-g` option and run it inside `gdb`. After running the program, and receiving segfault, type `backtrace`, so you can see where your code broke. This way segmentation fault will not be so mysterious.

Comment: Magic! Worked perfectly. Thanks. Do you know why it gave different behaviour for small and large n?

Comment: I think you were printing the garbage inside the file. However, with small values of `i`, `i + "\n"` were still pointing to the place in memory where have permissions to read.

Comment: Search the internet for "where string literals are stored".